# ¿Cómo deshabilitar chekcbox en sweetalert2 según una variable?

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

Tengo un input tipo chekcbox en un sweetalert2 y necesito deshabilitarlo según una variable que está por fuera del sweetalert2.

```
 Swal.fire({                      
                  title: 'Días de la semana a laborar',                                          
                  html:'<h3>Lunes <input type="checkbox" id="lunes" /></h3><p/>' +                               
                  confirmButtonText: 'Continue ',
                  showCancelButton: true,
                  preConfirm: () => {
                    return [                         
                      Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#lunes').checked,
                      
                    ]
                    
                  }
                })
```

No encuentro la forma de pasar una variable al interior del Swal.fire
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Puedes poner todo el código con una variable de prueba??

Comment: Alguien me ayudó a resolverlo pero ya no veo su publicación. Esta es la solución:  '+ (variableExterna ? 'checked' : ' ') + '   Lo que me faltaba eran las comillas simples y los signos +